# about Wine HQ and direct x 9

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, lenovo

I am using the recent version of Wine.I want to know that, should I install direct x9 to install games like Sand Andreas (GTA)  ...., or not?Does wine initially contain direct x 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine uses its own directx libraries files. But not all are available there. Also if available you have to enable it. You can always add any available libraries to your list: `Wine Configuration` -> `Libraries` -> `New Override for libraries` -> <kbd>Add</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> `Builtin(wine)`

But adding each and every libraries is somewhat a tedious task.

I am providing following link which will help you to use all available libraries and also install **DirectX** so that you can use missed libraries:

- [How to install DirectX in Wine and use all available libraries](http://www.dedoimedo.com/games/wine-directx.html)

Since it is a very long process, it is fairly not possible for me to describe each steps here. So should go to the above link and follow the steps.

Hope it works for you..

Answer (score 1):

Wine contains its own implementation of the DirectX libraries, with Direct3D 9 compatibility. Nevertheless, this implementation is not yet complete and causes issues with some games. Therefore, the answer to your question depends on the game you want to play.

I'd start without installing DirectX (relying on wines DirectX) and if the game does not run, use [winetricks](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/winetricks) to install certain Microsoft d3dx9*.dll files (or the full DirectX, but that often causes more troubles than it resolves).

A good starting point to find out if a particular game requires DirectX libraries is the [wine application database](http://appdb.winehq.org). Usually other users describe which dlls they needed to install to get the game running.

Another important thing: Since it depends on the game, whether or not certain DLL files are needed, it's good practise to install all games in separate WINEPREFIXes (see `man wine`) or use a tool that does this for you, like playonlinux or crossover. Another option would be to install to the same wineprefix but set up DLL overrides for each game executable, but this can be cumbersome in certain cases (think of a game consisting of more than one executable file).